# Outlook Addin: Office 2016 Desktop Client: SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not fully loaded

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am building an outlook addin. The addin in works fine on office online but fails on the desktop client (2016) with the error

`SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page. office.debug.js (1501,33)`

This is confusing given that i have tried the following and all work online...but not in the desktop client.

Version 1

```
Office.initialize = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      run();
    });
};
```

Version 2

```
Office.onReady(function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        run();
    });
});
```

Version 3:

```
Office.onReady(function() {
        run();
});
```

For some reason the desktop client fails.

Comment: Do you have a sample add-in that reproes this issue? Ensure that you are not seeing any script or network errors about loading javascript.

Comment: Could you please post a sample code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I figured out the issue. It places a template string in the javascript (\`${val}\`). Seems desktop client did not like this so the js file was never run.

Comment: @flexxxit. So what is the way to solve this problem on Desktop version

Comment: @RagavanRajan avoid using javascript markup that the desktop client may not be able to parse. In my case I used `\`somestring\`` which broke the JavaScript parser. You must assume that the parser is very naive. avoid ecmascript 6